# simple server in C

Tags: c

I created a simple TCP/IP server in c and it runs smoothly from my Linux machine. I can connect as localhost:80 as well as from different machines, but I obviously have to use the lab computer's IP.

My question is: how do I run a server form my own Mac OS X machine, let's say, and connect to it form outside? Not sure how to properly ask the question... how to assign a specific IP to my server? Sorry, I am still exploring this field!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe better on superuser.com

Comment: Maybe, or so it seems when you know the problem, but I understand that a young programmer may not know this is a configuration problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your local proxy or box is configured to allow entering connections, the easiest is to assign a fixed name that will be mapped to your (dynamic) IP.

There are a lot of dynamic DNS free solutions on the web (ex : http://www.no-ip.com/)

If you just want to make a one time test, you can see what IP you have with a service like this one : http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: Whatismyip.com will only tell you the address of the external router you have. (The likely case.)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a machine that has globally routable static ip address. And run your server on that machine.

Running it on your Mac laptop is okay but as you hop from one wifi network to other your server is no longer available.

Best way is to find a machine , a desktop in your lab or ar home connected to say comcast isp that has a static globally rout able ip and run your server on there.